# How to display custom 410 page with nextjs 13 app router

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to handle 410 codes on my nextjs 13 app router. I've setup a notFound page already as it's easily managed by nextjs. But I can't figure out how to display a custom 410 page in this version of nextjs!.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not supported by Next.js for now

See Github thread: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/53225

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).